# Terraform Create Ingress Application Gateway in AKS Node Resource Group

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

The AKS node resource group cannot already exist before creating the AKS cluster, so to create an application gateway in the same node resource group means that the application gateway needs to be created after the AKS cluster. But the ingress application gateway add-on is specified in the AKS cluster, which makes a circular dependency:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
    ...
    ingress_application_gateway {
      enabled    = true
      gateway_id = azurerm_application_gateway.example.id
    }
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "example" {
    ...
    resource_group_name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.node_resource_group
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to create the ingress app gateway in the AKS node resource group? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not possible to deploy the App Gateway in the AKS node resource group as you will need the App gateway to be created before AKS and AKS node resource group can't be a existing resource group.**

I tested the same in my environment with ***optional argument*** in ***AKS resource block*** which allows you to mention a name for the [`node_resource_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#node_resource_group).

---

I created a ***resource group*** and deployed the application gateway there and then mention in ***AKS resource block*** to use the ***same rg*** as ***node resource group*** with something like below:

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" { #existing resource group where the AKS is being deployed
  name="ansumantest"
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "noderg" {#new resource group where app gateway will be deployed and used as node resource group for AKS
  name     = "AKS_MG-ansumanaks-eastus"
  location = "East US"
}
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = "ansuman-appgw"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.noderg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.noderg.location
.....
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "ansuman-aks1"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "ansumanaks1"
  node_resource_group = azurerm_application_gateway.network.resource_group_name ##uses the appgw rg as Node rsource group

addon_profile {
  ingress_application_gateway {
    enabled    = true
    gateway_id = azurerm_application_gateway.network.id
  }
}
....
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

So, You can create ***Application Gateway*** in ***same resource group*** where the ***networking components*** and the ***AKS*** are being created.